# TeamCity - clean checkout for all builds in chain

Tags: teamcity, git-checkout

I know that when I am running a build manually, I can force it to do a clean checkout.

How do I do the same for all builds in a build chain?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell where you are having difficulty by your question. Can you be more specific?

In case this helps I accomplish just that by our own convention which is to create a VCS Root per build. For web application where you may want to clean only partial roots you can still have a new VCS Root that has as checkout directory the custom path to a sub folder of another build.

**Example**:

Build 1: 
Edit VCS Root:
Root: http://yourserver:8080/your_collection

Checkout Options -> Checkout directory: 
Auto (recommended)

Build 2: 
Edit VCS Root:
Root: http://yourserver:8080/your_collection

Checkout Options -> Checkout directory: 
Custom path (option)
/Subpath

Comment: I am creating the builds in the build chain and it happens that, for example, in a build step I move/change a file, which then causes a subsequent run of the same build to fail (because the VCS doesn't notice that something changed, apparently). All I want to do is to run the whole build chain saying "just dump all your workspaces and checkout everything anew".

Comment: Martin, I think we are talking about the same thing. I also have a build chain where every build is dependent on the previous one being successful. They all have their own VCS root and they have different checkout directories. This means that they have nothing in common as far as TC is concerned. Their only relationship is that one depends on another passing the build. Now, if your build fails because VCS is missing the change, you may want to investigate the VCS root itself, and open the checkout directory to see what is actually being checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to propagate "clean checkout" option from Run Custom Build dialog to all builds in chain. The feature request to vote for is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43043.

You can set "Clean all files in the checkout directory before the build" on build configuration > Version Control Settings page. In this case clean checkout will be always performed for the build configuration.